# TypeORM - Using transactions in Listener methods (BeforeUpdate)

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I have a NodeJS backend server using TypeORM, and I need to perform an insert every time an entity is updated. So I have the following code in my `BaseModel` class:

```
abstract class BaseModel {
// ...
  @BeforeUpdate()
  private async InsertBeforeUpdate() {
    let entToSave: BaseModel;
    // Create the entity that I want to insert
    await getManager().save(entToSave);
  }
}
```

Then, in my DAL:

```
const saveUser = (user: User) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    getManager().transaction(async manager => {
      manager
        .save(user)
        .then(() => {
          resolve('yay');
        })
        .catch(() => {
          reject(new Error('boo'));
        });
    });
  });
};
```

However, this raises a problem. If the save operation fails and the saveUser promise rejects, the insert performed in @BeforeUpdate doesn't exist on the same transaciton, and will save to the DB.

How can I access said transactional manager in the @BeforeUpdate listener function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `Subscriber` instead of a `Listener`, you can find more information on the [TypeORM documentation on subscribers](https://typeorm.io/#/listeners-and-subscribers/what-is-a-subscriber). Then you should add the subscriber to your `connectionOptions` (see [config here](https://typeorm.io/#/connection-options/common-connection-options))

For example, to transform your current hook into a subscriber, you can declare it as follows:

```
@EventSubscriber()
export class UserSubscriber implements EntitySubscriberInterface<User> {

    listenTo() {
        return User;
    }

    async beforeUpdate(event: UpdateEvent<Person>) {
        const entToSave = new WhateverEntity();
        // This will give you access to original manager, and so same transaction
        await event.manager
          .save(entToSave);
    }
}
```